# Tracking only specific directories and all files in root of git repository

Tags: git

I have repository. It contains many directories and files.

I want include only:

- several directories (bin, Documents);
- all files in root directory.

My `.gitignore` file now:

```
/*
!/bin
!/Documents
/Documents/ViberDownloads
/Documents/.~lock*
!/.gitignore
!/.bash_aliases
!/.bash_history
!/.bashrc
!/.gitconfig
!/.profile
```

I exclude all at first `/*`.

Add directories `bin` and `Documents` to whitelist.

Exclude from this directories some subdirectories (`ViberDownloads` and temp files of LibreOffice).

Now I manual add files from root directory by one.

Really root directory contains more files. But I do not want add each file manual.

How I can did it by patterns?

**UPD:**
@PetSerAl, @destoryer thanks.

```
/*/
!/bin
!/Documents
/Documents/ViberDownloads
/Documents/.~lock*
```

Comment: `/*` excludes all files in root, what you want is an initial `*` to exclude all followed by `!/*` and `!/Documents` etc.